# Normalize/scale dataframe in a certain range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scaling, normalize

I have the following Dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': {0: Timestamp('2022-02-08 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2022-02-08 00:10:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2022-02-08 00:20:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2022-02-08 00:30:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2022-02-08 00:40:00')},
 'wind power [W]': {0: 83.9, 1: 57.2, 2: 58.2, 3: 48.0, 4: 69.5}})
```

```
             DateTime  wind power [W]
0 2022-02-08 00:00:00            83.9
1 2022-02-08 00:10:00            57.2
2 2022-02-08 00:20:00            58.2
3 2022-02-08 00:30:00            48.0
4 2022-02-08 00:40:00            69.5
```

As you can see, 83.9 is the maximum value in my second column and 48.0 the minimum value. I want to normalize these values in a range between **0.6** and **8.4**, so that 83.9 would turn to 8.4 and 48.0 to 0.6. The rest of the numbers would fall somewhere in between.
So far I only managed to normalize the column to a range of 0-1 with the code:

```
df['normalized'] = (df['wind power [W]']-df['wind power [W]'].min())/(df['wind power [W]'].max()-df['wind power [W]'].min())
```

I don't know how to further proceed to get these numbers in my desired range. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) to perform feature scaling, `MinMaxScaler` supports a parameter called `feature_range` which allows us to specify the desired range of the transformed data

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0.6, 8.4))
df['normalized'] = scaler.fit_transform(df['wind power [W]'].values[:, None])
```

Alternatively if you don't want to use `MinMaxScaler`, here is a way scale data in pandas only:

```
w = df['wind power [W]'].agg(['min', 'max'])
norm = (df['wind power [W]'] - w['min']) / (w['max'] - w['min'])
df['normalized'] = norm * (8.4 - 0.6) + 0.6
```

---

```
print(df)

             DateTime  wind power [W]  normalized
0 2022-02-08 00:00:00            83.9    8.400000
1 2022-02-08 00:10:00            57.2    2.598886
2 2022-02-08 00:20:00            58.2    2.816156
3 2022-02-08 00:30:00            48.0    0.600000
4 2022-02-08 00:40:00            69.5    5.271309
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wikipedia definition of [feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) if you don't want to use `sklearn`:

```
a = 0.6
b = 8.4
x = df['wind power [W]']

df['normalized'] = a + (x - x.min()) * (b - a) / (x.max() - x.min())
print(df)

# Output
             DateTime  wind power [W]  normalized
0 2022-02-08 00:00:00            83.9    8.400000
1 2022-02-08 00:10:00            57.2    2.598886
2 2022-02-08 00:20:00            58.2    2.816156
3 2022-02-08 00:30:00            48.0    0.600000
4 2022-02-08 00:40:00            69.5    5.271309
```